# Should Stack Exchange remove downvotes from default?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

Would you think that Stack Exchange and other related sites should remove downvote function from their default?

If someone gives the worse answer they can provide another function to remove the bad answer. Can you suggest some functions if you're asked by Stack Exchange admin?

Does downvote imply your personality?

Do you feel really negative when we receive some downvotes?

Comment: Sorry to keep you up. Can you suggest how else one can indicate low quality?

Comment: Well, we are not facebook. And I don't feel negative because posts don't have feelings.

Comment: Downvotes are a necessary part of this site and should not be considered as personal commentary.

Comment: It's a win for all of the people providing low quality content.  It's a huge loss for anyone looking to find *quality* content.

Comment: @Oded All questions are closed and deleted by *default*. Only the good ones are undeleted and upvoted. :P:P:P:P:P

Comment: Down votes are not about you as a person, they are about the post.

Comment: @Mysticial I'd tweak it a bit; have them all closed but undeleted by default and delete them if they're not opened within 5 days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I don't think that.

Downvoting is an important way to deal with questions and answers that are destructive: questions that are terrible, and answers that are actively wrong.

We have a penalty (it costs 1 rep) on answer downvotes, to prevent spurious downvoting.

The consequence of downvotes to users, especially new users, is very different from that caused by no votes at all.

I wouldn't mind at all if the site would stop showing me questions I downvoted, because of course I do not like them.  But, I insist on the downvote capability.